# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel - Do not cycle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to initialize a Twitter Bootstrap Carousel without an automatic cycle? Setting `interval: false` does not cycle initially but once you click on next or prev, it starts cycling again. I don't want it to cycle at all.

**Edit**

Here is the jquery code that I'm using to initialize it:

```
$(function() {
    $('#carousel').carousel({interval: false});
});
```

To display an image in the carousel:

```
image_tag('image.png', :'data-target' => '#carousel', :'data-slide-to' => 1)
```

Comment: Could you paste some of your code plz?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can stop Bootstrap's carousel from cycling on page load by adding `data-interval="false"` to your `.carousel` div markup. (I wasn't able to get either of the above answers to work.)

Comment: Adding data-interval=false and data-ride="" will stop it from cycling.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for the "data-wrap" parameter

```
<div id="crsl1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-wrap="false">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: This stops it from initially scrolling, but once you click the left or right arrows, it starts scrolling again

Comment: Edit to my above comment: that's false.  data-wrap="false" stops the carousel from going around and around in an infinite pattern (whether automatically thru js or by the user clicking).  The OP is asking about preventing the automatic scrolling (whether infinite or not).  For that, data-interval="false" works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
   $('#carousel').carousel('pause');
});
```

or if that still doesn't do it, try this:

```
$('#carousel').carousel({interval: false});
$(document).on('mouseleave', '#carousel', function() {
    $(this).carousel('pause');
});
```

to reset the pause on mouseleave event.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Does carousel no have an option for never cycling?

Answer (score 0):

You can stop carousel events and control the sliding manually

```
$(function() {
    $('#carousel').carousel({interval: false});

    $(document).off('.bs.carousel.data-api');

    $('#carousel a').on('click', function (ev) {
        if ( $(ev.currentTarget).hasClass('right')) {
            $('#carousel').carousel('next');
        }

        if ( $(ev.currentTarget).hasClass('left')) {
            $('#carousel').carousel('prev');
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `data-ride="carousel"` remove from carousel and `$('#carousel-example').carousel({interval: false})`

Answer (score 0):

I forgot the same simple detail right now. It's very simple bro, but as i can see the question is still open. So here it goes:

just add data-wrap="false" at the main div of the carousel elment,

;)

Comment: data-wrap will only stop you from looping through the carousel when you have been through all the items in one direction.